# Conversion From String "Microsoft Anna" To Type 'Integer' Is Not Valid

Tags: vb.net

I am making a talking program which speaks when we write something in the RichTextBox and press the speak button to Speak. The speak button works perfectly fine sometimes, but now it's not working and saying

> Conversion From String "Microsoft Anna - English(United States)" To
>   Type 'Integer' Is Not Valid.

How do I convert it to String? The code is below:

```
Dim oVoice As New SpeechLib.SpVoice
            Dim cpFileStream As New SpeechLib.SpFileStream

            oVoice.Voice = oVoice.GetVoices.Item(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
            oVoice.Volume = TrackBar1.Value
            oVoice.Speak(RichTextBox1.Text, SpeechLib.SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault)
            oVoice = Nothing
```

What is wrong with my code? If it's not an integer, how can I convert it from String To integer?

Comment: How is the ComboBox1 populated?

Comment: Check your ComboBox... see if SelectedValue give you an integer.

Comment: also check this link out on MSDN: should work perfectly for your case : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723601%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: No!!Its Not Populated!!

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string to interger use TryParse

```
    Dim s As String = "x"

    ' Try to parse it.
    ' ... If it isn't a number, use -1.
    Dim num As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(s, num) Then
        num = -1
    End If
```

If s is a number then num will be the interger value of that number.

Comment: The issue is with the combobox selected item returning 'Microsoft Anna' while he wants the index. Your solution doesn't apply

Comment: @KeithMifsud Yep.. spotted that at the same time... but the user did ask how to convert from string to integer

Comment: Thanks But Now I Got Other Problem Sometimes A Error Coming When The Form Is Going To Be Loaded.The Error Says "InvalidArgument=Value   of '0' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.Parameter name: Selected Index"

Answer (score 0):

Populate you Combobox like this:

```
For Each T In New SpVoice.GetVoices
    ComboBox1.AddItem(T.GetDescription)
Next
```

then use:

```
oVoice.Voice = oVoice.GetVoices.Item(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)
```

Comment: When I am putting the populate code the SpVoice.GetVoices is not defined.

Comment: you can use oVoice.GetVoices or any other instance of SpeechLib.SpVoice

Comment: items of collections could not be modified in combobox1!!

Comment: Try
            Dim oVoice As New SpeechLib.SpVoice
            Dim cpFileStream As New SpeechLib.SpFileStream
            For Each T In oVoice.GetVoices
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(T.GetDescription)
            Next
            oVoice.Voice = oVoice.GetVoices.Item(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)
            oVoice.Volume = TrackBar1.Value
            oVoice.Speak(RichTextBox1.Text, SpeechLib.SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault)
            oVoice = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, 0 + 16, "Speaking Error!!")
        End Try

Comment: the foreach loop should be in form_load... in order to populate the combobox and let the user select whichever voice he wants... also try combobox1.items.add(t.getDescription) '(Still in the form_load method)

Comment: @SudhirSundar - Please do not put code in a comment.  It is almost impossible to read.  Please edit your question and add any additional code there.

Answer (score -1):

Here You Go @Keith Mifsud

```
Try
            Me.Location = My.Settings.Location
            Me.Size = My.Settings.Size
            ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = My.Settings.Selected
            Dim x As New SpeechLib.SpVoice
            Dim arrVoices As SpeechLib.ISpeechObjectTokens = x.GetVoices
            Dim arrLst As New ArrayList
            For i As Integer = 0 To arrVoices.Count - 1
                arrLst.Add(arrVoices.Item(i).GetDescription)
            Next
            ComboBox1.DataSource = arrLst
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, 0 + 16, "Speaking Error!!")
        End Try
```

Comment: OK... CALM DOWN lol... what you're doing is good, remember the foreach loop i gave you... you're already doing it...

replace the Dim arrLst As New ArrayList
            For i As Integer = 0 To arrVoices.Count - 1
                arrLst.Add(arrVoices.Item(i).GetDescription)
            Next
            ComboBox1.DataSource = arrLst

with my foreach loop

Comment: Thanks Now Everything Is Working.The Problem Was The ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = My.Resources.Selected.I Removed It And It Now Works.Now Can You Help Me How To Save Setting On ComboBox.

Comment: please mark my answer as the correct one then :) Yes ill give you some useful links and sample code

Comment: check this out for saving settings http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15013/Windows-Forms-User-Settings-in-C

Comment: Is this an answer to your question?  If not, you should update your question by editing it and adding this code there.

Comment: Sorry For Asking You A Silly Question But Can You Help Me With GameMaker Now.In Game Maker I Am Making A Level Editor Engine.I Have Watched Many Videoes On How To Make A Menu List In Which You Select One Item From The Menu List And Left Click To Create That Object Coded In Each Menu Item Included And Right Click To Delete Each.

Comment: Thanks Now Can You Help Me With My Other Questions.